# Browser plugin to suggest words as you type

Tags: windows, web-browser, language

Is there any browser plugin (doesn't matter which browser, as long as it runs on Windows) that can give you a list of English word suggestions as you type inside a textarea (e.g. like this textarea where you type the question, or in email content area)?

For example, you start typing a letter 'a', it pop-ups a list of words starting with 'a', ordered by how frequent you use those words.

Think about those typing aids on smart phones, but this one is for PC browsers.

Best if the list of word suggestions is customizable (i.e. you can add/remove/edit the words).

Answer (score 2):

I found the Chrome extension [Read&Write for Google](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/readwrite-for-google/inoeonmfapjbbkmdafoankkfajkcphgd).

It is actually designed as an app to help those with learning or other disabilities that restrict accessibility for people but it has word prediction and a host of other pretty dang handy functionality even for the abled.

Functionality includes (emphasis mine):

> Read&Write for Google™ offers a range of powerful support tools to help students gain confidence with reading and writing.
>
> - Hear words, passages, or whole documents read aloud with easy-to-follow colour highlighting
> - See the meaning of words explained with text and picture dictionaries
> - Hear text translated into other languages
> - **Predicts the next word as you type**
> - Highlight interesting or relevant text and collect it for use in other documents